# how to reset file attributes with FileCopy()

Tags: inno-setup

I use  Filecopy() function to copy files  from CDROM media, it seems that READONLY attribute is copied and it causes problem with reinstall.

how to remove read only attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built in [support functions](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptfunctions) don't have a routine to do this.

So it comes down to one of several other options.

1. You could call `ShellExecute` using the `attrib -r C:\path\FileName.txt`
2. You could build the functionality into a DLL and import the DLL
3. You could use a COM object to do this
4. Call the Windows API directly. **UPDATED**

Here is an example function that does it with COM

```
procedure RemoveReadOnly(FileSpec : String);
var
 FSO : Variant;
 File : Variant;
begin
 FSO := CreateOleObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
 File := FSO.GetFile(FileSpec);
 if File.attributes and 1 then // Check if Readonly already
    File.attributes := File.attributes - 1;
end;
```

MSDN Contains the documentation on [FilesSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6dw7aeh%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and the use of [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tx15443%28VS.85%29.aspx).

**UPDATED**

Here is an example of calling the Windows API directly, which is best option.

```
function GetFileAttributes(lpFileName: PAnsiChar): DWORD;
 external 'GetFileAttributesA@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function SetFileAttributes(lpFileName: PAnsiChar; 
   dwFileAttributes: DWORD): BOOL; 
external 'SetFileAttributesA@kernel32.dll stdcall';

procedure RemoveReadOnly(FileName : String);
var
 Attr : DWord;
begin
  Attr := GetFileAttributes(FileName);
  if (Attr and 1) = 1  then          
  begin
    Attr := Attr -1;
    SetFileAttributes(FileName,Attr);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: But surely `if File.attributes and 1 then` doesn't comp... interpret? `ìf` requires a boolean, not an integer.

Comment: @Andreas:  I placed this function in a InnoSetup Script and tested it, and it worked as expected.    I placed the link to the MSDN article reference I used.

Comment: @Rob: Oh, yes, I see it isn't integer, but variant, sorry!

Comment: Thanks, what is minimum OS requirement for this scripting to work? Does it require e.g. Win2000, Xp, etc..

Comment: @Tom: I searched and could not find the requirements, I remember using it back on Windows 98.   It was default thing to use with Visual Basic.

Comment: Realized it would be better to call the Windows API directly.  So I added an example of doing that.